# pact: pact maven plugin support record-deployment/releases?

Tags: pact

Have pact maven plugin supported record-deployment/release now?
https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/recording_deployments_and_releases/

It looks like pact-broker client cli tool is up-to-date. While pact maven plugin does not.
I'm thinking whether turn to pact-broker client cli tool instead of maven plugin even my project is a maven project. :(

Answer (score 0):

There are no plans to add this command to the maven library. Our long term plan is to keep/move as much as possible of the Pact Broker interactions to the Pact Broker client. I do recommend adding the cli to your project.